# Polymorphism questions in Java

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

```
public class a{
  public void sup()
  {
    System.out.println("1");
  }
 public class b extends a
{
  public void sub
 {
      System.out.println("2");
 }
```

When I instantiate an object like this and run it:

```
a ob1 = new b();
ob1.sub();
```

There would be a compilation error that says the sub() method in ob1 is not defined. If I want to instantiate an object of the class "a" and it could still use the method in class b. What is the appropriate way to do that?

Comment: `sup` vs `sub`. You have a typo. Fix it.

Comment: Is this the *actual* code you're using?  You're missing parens on `sub`.

Comment: Use "super" keyword https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html
but be careful about Barbara Liskov substitution principle http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the declaration `A ob1 = ...`, you can only use methods and fields of the class `A`. This is because `ob1` is declared as a reference of type `A`. This check is done at compile-time and the *actual* run-time type of `ob1` doesn't matter.

If you *know* that `ob1` actually references an object of type `B` (as you do in this case), and you want to have it declared as `A` but use it as `B`, you can cast it to `B`:

```
((B) ob1).sub();
```